# How to enhance the response in apollo client with react only once

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I make a GraphQL query where I get back a lot of data and than I calculate the min and max values. As the calculating is quite time consuming I would like to only do it when I receive the value. Unfortunately the `props` method is called every time the component is rerendered even there was no new call, and the data comes from the store. How can I limit the calculation to the points where I really get new data

```
graphql(DataQuery, {
    options: ({ id }) => ({
        variables: {
            id,
        },
    }),
    props: ({ data: { result} }) => ({
        data: result,
        min: getMin(result),
        max: getMax(result),
    }),
})
```

Answer (score 3):

This problem is similar to [the problem in redux](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data) where `mapStateToProps()` will be called again every time the store updates repeating costy calculations.

You can solve that by using [memorized selectors](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect):

```js
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'

const getMinMax = createSelector(
  result => result,
  result => ({
      min: getMin(result),
      max: getMax(result),
  })
)

graphql(DataQuery, {
    options: ({ id }) => ({
        variables: {
            id,
        },
    }),
    props: ({ data: {result} }) => ({
        data: result,
        ...getMinMax(result), // will only re-calculate if result changed
    }),
})
```

Memorized selectors remember the last result of a call and keep returning that on subsequent calls as long as the input does not change.